# S3 objects won't delete after applying lifecycle rule that contains expiration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I added a lifecycle rule to my S3 bucket. The purpose is to delete any object older than 30 days. Therefore, I configured the following settings on the S3 Bucket:

- Versioning property is enabled
- A new lifecycle rule was added

Here are the lifecycle rule configurations:

- Rule scope: Apply to all objects in the bucket
- Transitions were not configured (since those S3 objects should be deleted and not archived somewhere else)
- Expiration configurations:

  > both current version and previous versions checked
  >
  > Expire current version of object: After *30* days from object creation
  >
  > Permanently delete previous versions: After *1* days from becoming a previous version
  >
  > Clean up expired object delete markers and incomplete multipart uploads is greyed out since I checked "Expire current version of object"
  >
  > Clean up incomplete multipart uploads: After *7* days from start of upload
  >
  > Visual display in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyey8.png)

After the creation of that rule I saw that the rule is enabled, and the expiration date is displayed properly on the desired S3 objects:

> The last modified timestamp is a month before the expiration date
>
> Visual display in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyIYc.png)

I'll mention that unlike other questions that were raised in here, the objects that I want to delete (on a regular basis) are small (less then a KB) and there are not many of them (not more then 100 totally).

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [S3 Locking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock.html)?

This an prevent an object being deleted before a certain period of time.

Alternatively try enabling [S3 logging in CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html) for your specific bucket and see if their are any failed API calls.

Comment: Hmm, might be worth adding the CloudTrail Audit for this bucket then to see if the actions are attempted.